# How can I compare Firestore time with Go time.Now()?

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore

I use Go to build my game server. I am going to compare a time from `time.Now()` and one from a Firestore field. How can I do that in Go?

```
        playerDataSnap, err := Instace.FireStoreClient.Collection("PlayerData").Doc(playerUID).Get(Instace.Context)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("EventModeFee Get PlayerData Fail: %v", err)
        return
    }
    playerData := playerDataSnap.Data()
    if value, exist := playerData["EventPlayTimes"]; exist {
        eventPlayTimes = value.(int64)
    }

    if discount_Subscribe > 0 {
        if value, exist := playerData["SubscriptionExpiredDate"]; exist { //Get Subscribe expired time
            var expireTimeStamp = value //<-------------timestamp from firestore field

            if time.Now().Before(expireTimeStamp) {//<---------------expireTimeStamp is not a valid type, but How can I convert it to a valid type
                isSubscribed = true
            }
        }
    }
```

`expireTimeStamp` is not a valid type, but how can I convert it to a valid one?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I can directly assert the timestamp from Firestore field to `time.Time` with the following code:

```golang
if time.Now().Before(expireTimeStamp.(time.Time)) {
    isSubscribed = true
}
```